# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files are defined

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, dex

I'm getting an error at runtime stating: "DraggableGridViewSample] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/animoto/android/views/DraggableGridView$1;"

How might this be avoided? I've tried removing the android-support-v4 jar from my libs folder and clicking Android Tools > Add Android Support Library but I cannot seem to resolve this issue.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Double check all your includes, I had this in the past and it was because I had duplicate includes for JAR libs in my project.

Comment: I'm not even sure exactly what you mean... how can I check that?

Comment: Source can be found here: https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView

Comment: I added a screenshot of my build path - do you see anything in there I should change?

Comment: Can you try to REMOVE the DraggableGridView.jar from the build path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [source](https://github.com/thquinn/DraggableGridView) you provided, the `DraggableGridView` class is already under `src`. So adding the jar that contains the same is redundant and dex will complain about duplicate definitions.

To fix it, just remove the `DraggableGridView.jar` from your project.

Comment: Thanks! BTW - I have another somewhat simple question you might be able to answer...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20982317/adding-different-onclick-listeners-to-gridview-items

Answer (score 1):

Project - build Path - Libraries.
Check if android private libraries contains the same jars listed in the libraries in the first place. If so remove private libraries and leave the jars.
That worked for me.

Comment: apart from the above steps you need to add the jars inside the libs folder externally

Answer (score 0):

Add all the jars in the libs folder externally and uncheck the android private libraries this should work