# adding onClick listener to gridView items (to launch unique intents depending on position)

Tags: java, android, gridview, android-intent, onclicklistener

I have a gridView and I'd like to launch a different intent depending on the position of the item clicked.

I've instantiated the following onClick listener which includes the value for position:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

But I believe I'll need to add an if statement within it to determine which intent to launch depending on this position. So far I've come up with the following but I do not believe it is exactly what I'm looking for.

```
if position = 1 { Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class); }else if position = 2 { Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class); }
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

/**
 * This activity presents a screen with a grid on which images can be added and
 * moved around. It also defines areas on the screen where the dragged views can
 * be dropped. Feedback is provided to the user as the objects are dragged over
 * these drop zones.
 * 
 *

* Like the DragActivity in the previous version of the DragView example
 * application, the code here is derived from the Android Launcher code.
 * 
 *

* The original Launcher code required a long click (press) to initiate a
 * drag-drop sequence. If you want to see that behavior, set the variable
 * mLongClickStartsDrag to true. It is set to false below, which means that any
 * touch event starts a drag-drop.
 * 
 */

```
public class DragActivity extends Activity implements View.OnLongClickListener,
View.OnClickListener, View.OnTouchListener // ,
// AdapterView.OnItemClickListener
{

    /**
     */
    // Constants

    private static final int HIDE_TRASHCAN_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST;
    private static final int SHOW_TRASHCAN_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    private static final int ADD_OBJECT_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 2;
    private static final int CHANGE_TOUCH_MODE_MENU_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
    private boolean isErase = true;
    private EditText et;
    private TextView tx;

    /**
     */
    // Variables

    private DragController mDragController; // Object that handles a drag-drop
    // sequence. It intersacts with
    // DragSource and DropTarget
    // objects.
    private DragLayer mDragLayer; // The ViewGroup within which an object can be
    // dragged.
    private DeleteZone mDeleteZone; // A drop target that is used to remove
    // objects from the screen.
    private int mImageCount = 0; // The number of images that have been added to
    // screen.
    private ImageCell mLastNewCell = null; // The last ImageCell added to the
    // screen when Add Image is clicked.
    private boolean mLongClickStartsDrag = true; // If true, it takes a long
    // click to start the drag
    // operation.
    // Otherwise, any touch
    // event starts a drag.

    public static final boolean Debugging = false; // Use this to see extra
    // toast messages.

    /**
     */
    // Methods

    /**
     * Add a new image so the user can move it around. It shows up in the
     * image_source_frame part of the screen.
     * 
     * @param resourceId
     *            int - the resource id of the image to be added
     */

    public void addNewImageToScreen(int resourceId) {
        if (mLastNewCell != null)
            mLastNewCell.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        FrameLayout imageHolder = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.image_source_frame);
        if (imageHolder != null) {
            FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    Gravity.CENTER);
            ImageCell newView = new ImageCell(this);
            newView.setImageResource(resourceId);
            imageHolder.addView(newView, lp);
            newView.mEmpty = false;
            newView.mCellNumber = -1;
            mLastNewCell = newView;
            mImageCount++;

            // Have this activity listen to touch and click events for the view.
            newView.setOnClickListener(this);
            newView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            newView.setOnTouchListener(this);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Add one of the images to the screen so the user has a new image to move
     * around. See addImageToScreen.
     * 
     */

    public void addNewImageToScreen() {
        int resourceId = R.drawable.sqwhite;
        addNewTextToScreen();
        int m = mImageCount % 3;

        if (m == 1)
            resourceId = R.drawable.sqdrk;

        else if (m == 2)
            resourceId = R.drawable.sqwhite;
        addNewImageToScreen(resourceId);

    }

    private void addNewTextToScreen() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //  et.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        if (isErase) {
            tx.setText(et.getText().toString());
        } else {
            tx.setText("");
            et.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        isErase = !isErase;
    }

    /**
     * Handle a click on a view.
     * 
     */

    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mLongClickStartsDrag) {
            // Tell the user that it takes a long click to start dragging.
            //toast("Press and hold to drag an image.");


        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle a click of the Add Image button
     * 
     */

    public void onClickAddImage(View v) {
        addNewImageToScreen();
    }

    /**
     * onCreate - called when the activity is first created.
     * 
     * Creates a drag controller and sets up three views so click and long click
     * on the views are sent to this activity. The onLongClick method starts a
     * drag sequence.
     * 
     */

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.demo);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        tx = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.image_grid_view);

        if (gridView == null)
            toast("Unable to find GridView");
        else {
            gridView.setAdapter(new ImageCellAdapter(this));
            // gridView.setOnItemClickListener (this);
        }

        mDragController = new DragController(this);
        mDragLayer = (DragLayer) findViewById(R.id.drag_layer);
        mDragLayer.setDragController(mDragController);
        mDragLayer.setGridView(gridView);

        mDragController.setDragListener(mDragLayer);
        // mDragController.addDropTarget (mDragLayer);

        mDeleteZone = (DeleteZone) findViewById(R.id.delete_zone_view);

        // Give the user a little guidance.
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                getResources().getString(R.string.instructions),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /**
     * Build a menu for the activity.
     * 
     */

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        menu.add(0, HIDE_TRASHCAN_MENU_ID, 0, "Hide Trashcan").setShortcut('1',
                'c');
        menu.add(0, SHOW_TRASHCAN_MENU_ID, 0, "Show Trashcan").setShortcut('2',
                'c');
        menu.add(0, ADD_OBJECT_MENU_ID, 0, "Add View").setShortcut('9', 'z');
        menu.add(0, CHANGE_TOUCH_MODE_MENU_ID, 0, "Change Touch Mode");

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Handle a click of an item in the grid of cells.
     * 
     */

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        ImageCell i = (ImageCell) v;
        trace("onItemClick in view: " + i.mCellNumber);
    }

    /**
     * Handle a long click. If mLongClick only is true, this will be the only
     * way to start a drag operation.
     * 
     * @param v
     *            View
     * @return boolean - true indicates that the event was handled
     */

    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if (mLongClickStartsDrag) {

            // trace ("onLongClick in view: " + v + " touchMode: " +
            // v.isInTouchMode ());

            // Make sure the drag was started by a long press as opposed to a
            // long click.
            // (Note: I got this from the Workspace object in the Android
            // Launcher code.
            // I think it is here to ensure that the device is still in touch
            // mode as we start the drag operation.)
            if (!v.isInTouchMode()) {
                toast("isInTouchMode returned false. Try touching the view again.");
                return false;
            }
            return startDrag(v);
        }

        // If we get here, return false to indicate that we have not taken care
        // of the event.
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Perform an action in response to a menu item being clicked.
     * 
     */

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case HIDE_TRASHCAN_MENU_ID:
            if (mDeleteZone != null)
                mDeleteZone.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            return true;
        case SHOW_TRASHCAN_MENU_ID:
            if (mDeleteZone != null)
                mDeleteZone.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        case ADD_OBJECT_MENU_ID:
            // Add a new object to the screen;
            addNewImageToScreen();
            return true;
        case CHANGE_TOUCH_MODE_MENU_ID:
            mLongClickStartsDrag = !mLongClickStartsDrag;
            String message = mLongClickStartsDrag ? "Changed touch mode. Drag now starts on long touch (click)."
                    : "Changed touch mode. Drag now starts on touch (click).";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * This is the starting point for a drag operation if mLongClickStartsDrag
     * is false. It looks for the down event that gets generated when a user
     * touches the screen. Only that initiates the drag-drop sequence.
     * 
     */

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
        // If we are configured to start only on a long click, we are not going
        // to handle any events here.
        if (mLongClickStartsDrag)
            return false;

        boolean handledHere = false;

        final int action = ev.getAction();

        // In the situation where a long click is not needed to initiate a drag,
        // simply start on the down event.
        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            handledHere = startDrag(v);
        }

        return handledHere;
    }

    /**
     * Start dragging a view.
     * 
     */

    public boolean startDrag(View v) {
        DragSource dragSource = (DragSource) v;

        // We are starting a drag. Let the DragController handle it.
        mDragController.startDrag(v, dragSource, dragSource,
                DragController.DRAG_ACTION_MOVE);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Show a string on the screen via Toast.
     * 
     * @param msg
     *            String
     * @return void
     */

    public void toast(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } // end toast

    /**
     * Send a message to the debug log. Also display it using Toast if Debugging
     * is true.
     */

    public void trace(String msg) {
        Log.d("DragActivity", msg);
        if (!Debugging)
            return;
        toast(msg);
    }

} // end class
```

Answer (score 2):

from the android documentation for GridView:

```
gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

edit:
It looks like the addNewImageToScreen() is where you are adding the ImageCells, so assuming that you can generate the intent in that scope..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class); // or whatever you want to run
ImageCell newView = ...
newView.setTag( intent );
```

then in your onItemClick:
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(HelloGridView.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = (Intent) v.getTag();
        // now you can startActivity with your intent..
    }

Comment: Let's say I wanted to launch a different intent with each position... would I simply use an if statement within the onClick listener such as:

if position = 1 { 

Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class);

}else if position = 2 {  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity1.class); }

Comment: What do you mean by position? Do you mean gridview item? If so, then look a little closer at the answer. It tells you the position which will be the item that was clicked.

Comment: I know... I see that - I'm asking how I can start a different intent depending on the position clicked (I'm going to remove the toasts entirely)

Comment: `View view` is ["The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)"](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)

Enclose your reference data in the view and check for it in the listener. Start an activity based on the stored value.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how this can be accomplished... I still need help with this if anyone would like to provide a bit more detail on how this can be accomplished

Comment: or provided an answer showing how I might be able to launch different intents/activities? I need to remove the toasts entirely so the current example isn't much help..

Comment: You've got an adapter in play to generate the icons and text for each cell, so it would make sense to store the intent for each cell as part of the data in your adapter.  However you might just be using a switch statement using the position to decide the cell contents.  In that case, when you configure the view in your adapter's getView, you can also create the Intent that should be started and store it in the view's tag.  The view for the clicked cell is passed in to onItemClicked() so you would just need to grab the intent from it (  Intent intent = (Intent)v.getTag() )

Comment: Can you update your answer to show how such a switch statement might be implemented? (I'm working on it on my end but I'm having trouble getting it to work correctly)

Comment: If you think I should start a new question - just let me know - I just need to figure out how to get this if / switch statement working in my current implementation : ) (I really appreciate your help BTW!)

Answer (score 0):

Make a string array with your classes, the in the onItemClick () create another string declared with the position (item) clicked.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String [] classes = {"act1",  "act2"}; // activity files

    GridView gridView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            String pos = classes[position];

            try {
            Class start = Class.forName("com.company.app." + pos); //Your package name

            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, start);
            startActivity(i);
            } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

            Toast.makeText(
                getApplicationContext(),
                ((TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.label))
                .getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```